# SoapUI to read request parameters from a file ( free version)

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a file with following contents

```
987656   
987534
```

I have a Groovy script as following as a test step before my test :

```
def myTestCase = context.testCase
new File("filepath/data1.txt").eachLine { line ->
  myTestCase.setPropertyValue("inputValue", line)
  inputValue = context.expand( '${#TestCase#inputValue}' )
  log.info inputValue
}
```

The log output for the script gives me both the values from the file :

```
987656
987534
```

I have a Testcase custom property set up as "inputValue" and in my test I call the parameter as

```
 <enr:Id>${#TestCase#inputValue}</enr:Id>
```

During execution the test always runs for the last value "987534" and not for both the inputs.

What should I be doing to execute the test for all the values present in the text file?

Thanks

Comment: That is expected. Becuase, in the script it reads all the contents and the last line value is as custom property. Hence the result you see. You have to run the test for each instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to loop through values like that is to, in the `eachLine` loop, call the SOAP step, like this:

```
def myTestCase = context.testCase
new File("filepath/data1.txt").eachLine { line ->
    myTestCase.setPropertyValue("inputValue", line)
    inputValue = context.expand( "${#TestCase#inputValue}" )
    log.info inputValue

    //define the step
    def soapTestStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("YourSOAPRequestName").name
    
    //call the step
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(soapTestStep)

    //if you want to do something with the response XML
    def responseSOAP = context.expand("${YourSOAPRequestName#Response}")

    //if you want to check a value in the response XML
    def responseSection = responseSOAP =~ /someNode>(.*)<\/someNode/   
    def responseValue = responseSection[0][1]
    log.info "response: ${responseValue}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ou_ryperd. When I tried the above, the tests  got executed for both the values in data file 987656, 987534. However the test ran for 3 steps repeating the last value twice.